# Intents for opening the e-mail client and the text message client

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to use intents to open some clients in Android:

1. For the e-mail client I'm using ACTION_VIEW with a mailto URI, and I'm getting the message: "Unsupported Action! That action is not currently supported". Is it an issue only on the emulator, and is supposed to work on a device? (I don't have one, so I can't check)
2. For the text message I'm using ACTION_SENDTO with a tel URI, and I'm simply getting no response. What's the right action for it?

I know about the constants CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL and CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING, but they were only added in the latest version (API 15).

Thanks.

Comment: When I run the emulator, it won't let me invoke email intents either. It basically says there is nothing found to handle the intent (don't know the exact msg). It works fine on actual devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point is ok.

The second, you have to call action view with uri like "sms:"...

Comment: Thanks for the "sms:" tip. I wish there were a way to open an e-mail client with the emulator...

Answer (score 1):

I use this code below for E-mailing. I get an error in the emulator but it works on real devices

```
Intent emailDeveloper = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailDeveloper.setType("message/rfc822");
emailDeveloper.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL       , new String[]{"YourEmail@email.com"});
emailDeveloper.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "E-mail subject");
emailDeveloper.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Message text");

try 
{
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailDeveloper, "Send e-mail..."));
} 

catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
{

    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Error finding E-mail application", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```